# SSIS Argument SQL for option Copy is not valid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I am trying to do a SSIS package deployment to SQL server 2008. I generated the manifest file but double clicking it didn't open the deployment wizard.

I have tried to execute the dtutil command from the command prompt but getting an error Argument SQL for option Copy is not valid

Following is the command that I am using

[image]

I need to deploy to SQL server 2008 R2. I also need to know how and where are the dtsconfig files stored in sql server. Please help

Comment: Do you have to do it using a manifest file, or will any other method do?

Comment: this may help your command line error, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/215/command-line-deployment-tool-for-ssis-packages/

Comment: How do I deploy the config file in sql server

Comment: Hi Tab, need not be manifest file. I am looking at what is usually preferred techniques. Ideally if it can be done using scripts it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

To copy a package from file system to an MSDB database you have to use the following syntax:

```
dtutil /FILE c:\sourcepkg.dtsx /DestServer <servername> /COPY SQL;destpkgname
```

So in your case, assuming that the package path is `C:\Development\CoreAnalytics\Trunk\src\Willis.CoreReference.ETL\Willis.CoreReference.ETL\bin\Deployment\Core.ReferenceETL.dtsx` and that the SQL Server name is `MYSERVER\SQL2008R2`, so you have to use the following command:

*Having a windows Authentication*

```
dtutil /FILE C:\Development\CoreAnalytics\Trunk\src\Willis.CoreReference.ETL\Willis.CoreReference.ETL\bin\Deployment\Core.ReferenceETL.dtsx /DestServer MYSERVER\SQL2008R2 /COPY SQL;CoreReferenceETL
```

*Having a SQL Authentication (user:sa - password:123456)*

```
dtutil /FILE C:\Development\CoreAnalytics\Trunk\src\Willis.CoreReference.ETL\Willis.CoreReference.ETL\bin\Deployment\Core.ReferenceETL.dtsx /DestServer MYSERVER\SQL2008R2  /DestUser sa and /DestPassword 123456 /COPY SQL;CoreReferenceETL
```

**References**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility

Comment: Is it ok to use sql server authentication in this case ?

Comment: @amd https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To copy a package from a local file system to an instance of SQL Server hosted on another computer, use the following syntax ([MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162820(v=sql.105).aspx)):

```
dtutil /FILE c:\sourcepkg.dtsx /DestServer <servername> /COPY SQL;destpkgname
```

Graphically you can try by **Importing the .dtsx file** from local to SQL Server or to the package store. Follow below steps:

1. Launch SSMS and Connect to Integration Services
2. Stored Packages>MSDB>Righ Click
3. Select Import Package and Browse the required file

[image]

4. Select the Protection level as per requirement, Press OK

**For Package Configuration**, If it is an existing package with dtsConfiguration was in previous SQL Server, Script out the table from previous server and run in new server. You can try new configuraton from below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the most reliable way of deploying a package in SQL Server 2008 has been to import it from the file system using an SSIS connection in SSMS.

1. Open SSMS and open an Integration Services connection to the server you want to deploy to.
2. Open Stored Packages and right click the folder where you want to store the package and click "Import Package.."
3. For Package Location, choose File System.
4. Click the ellipsis next to Package Path and navigate to your SSIS Solution, go into \bin\release and choose the dtsx file you want to import.
5. As for the config file, manually place it in the file system.  Use the path specified in Package Configurations of the SSIS package.